# Implementing custom gradient for TensorFlow matrix exponential

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I'm trying to build a custom layer in TensorFlow using coefficients of matrices in an exponential, so that the layer has basis matrices M1 and M2 and fitting coefficients a and b, so the layer acts on an input vector with the matrix exp(a M1 + b M2).

There's no closed form solution for the gradient of this, and TensorFlow can't take the gradient of a matrix exponential anyway, so I need to implement a custom gradient with respect to a and b within my layer class. Here's the code for the layer:

```
class Matrix(layers.Layer):
    """Class for the linear transformation layer in the network"""

    def __init__(self, dim=1):

        # This won't work for arbitrary dimensionality
        dims = [1, 2, 3]
        assert dim in dims, "Dimensionality {} is not 1, 2, or 3".format(dim)
        super(Matrix, self).__init__()

        A_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.dim = dim

        # define the basis matrices to generate the Lie transform
        if self.dim == 1:
            M1 = np.array([[0., -1.],
                           [1., 0.]]) # basis 1
            M2 = np.array([[1., 0.],
                           [0.,-1.]]) # basis 2

            self.basis_matrices=[M1, M2]

            self.A = tf.Variable(initial_value=A_init(shape=(2,),
                                                  dtype='float32'),
                             trainable=True)

            # dims 2 and 3 are still pending        

    def compute_matrix_exp(self, zed):

        if self.dim == 1:
            exp_arg = self.A[0]*self.basis_matrices[0] + self.A[1]*self.basis_matrices[1]
            M = tf.linalg.expm(exp_arg)

        return tf.matmul(M, zed)

    def compute_matrix_exp_grad(self, zed):

        if self.dim == 1:
            exp_arg = self.A[0]*self.basis_matrices[0] + self.A[1]*self.basis_matrices[1]
            M = tf.linalg.expm(exp_arg)

            dM_dA0 = tf.matmul(self.basis_matrices[0], M) #approximate
            dM_dA1 = tf.matmul(self.basis_matrices[1], M) #approximate

        return [tf.matmul(dM_dA0, zed), tf.matmul(dM_dA1, zed)]

    @tf.custom_gradient
    def call(self, zed):

        def grad(zed):

            grad = self.compute_matrix_exp_grad(zed)

        return self.compute_matrix_exp(zed), grad
```

I'm pretty new to TensorFlow, so I'm not sure how best to implement a custom gradient anyway. Thanks very much for your help.

**Edit:** I've added my attempt to get the custom gradient out, and have discovered that it doesn't train the a and b variables, nor does it seem to even call `call()`, so I am confused.

Comment: Not sure what is the question. You can use [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) to implement your own gradient in a relatively simple way. For example, if you use it with `compute_matrix_exp` you would return the result of the operation along with another function that does the gradient computation.

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly implement `tf.custom_gradient` inside a layer class, if that makes sense.